# Interactive ssh connection does not work

Tags: ssh

For some reason I have a master script that required below coding:

```
vi test_run.sh    
#!/bin/sh
ssh -tt 192.168.1.20
```

To execute the command I run:

```
cat test_run.sh | sh -
```

I'm able to connect to the remote server but I can't issue any command there, e.g `ls` follow by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, cause the screen to hang.

Comment: Why are you doing `cat foo | sh -` instead of just `foo`?

Comment: @Sparhawk Probably because they haven't `chmod +x test_run.sh`.  Still, `sh test_run.sh` would have been better than the `cat` through a pipe.

Comment: does it return something if you type  `ssh 192.168.1.20 'echo yes'` ? if no i might be an ssh problem, if yes if might then be an MTU problem between your machine and 192.168.1.20.

Answer (score 3):

`ssh` will inherit the standard input stream of the shell that executes it.

The standard input of the shell that executes `ssh` is being used to read the shell script (from the pipe from `cat`), and is therefore not available for interactively issuing commands to `ssh`.  This is why you are trying with `-tt` to make the `ssh` session interactive (`ssh` would complain otherwise, saying *Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal*), but it doesn't work because, as mentioned, the stream that is used supply it with commands from the user is being used by the shell to read the actual script.

Instead, run the script as usual:

```
sh test_run.sh
```

This would leave the standard input stream available for you to issue commands interactively to the remote shell session, and your invocation of `ssh` would also not need `-tt` at all.

If your script was a bit longer:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -tt 192.168.1.20
hostname
echo "DONE"
```

and if you ran it as

```
cat test_run.sh | sh -
```

you would notice that the machine that executes both `hostname` and the `echo` is actually the *remote* machine.  This is because the standard input of the shell (connected to the stream read from `cat`, containing the script) will be passed on to `ssh`.  This has the effect of passing the commands in the script on to the shell started on the remote system (as if you typed them into the remote shell).